# Structuring continuation types?

Tags: haskell, types, continuations, newtype, type-synonyms

I'm going over continuations and I've come across two different approaches to structuring continuation types:

```
newtype C r a = C {runC :: (a -> r) -> r}

exampleFunction :: String -> C Bool String
exampleFunction s = C $ \t -> if length s > 10 then t s else False

continuationFunction :: String -> Bool
continuationFunction s = True

main = do
 let suspendedFunc = exampleFunction "testing"
 let completedFunc = runC suspendedFunc $ continuationFunction
```

versus the approach taken in [Poor Mans Concurrency](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=7F9022E04C0AE213B74964BA29E2E69D?doi=10.1.1.39.8039&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

```
type C r a = (a -> r) -> r

exampleFunction :: String -> C Bool String
exampleFunction s = \t -> if length s > 10 then t s else False

...
```

I understand that the latter approach doesn't use an explicit data constructor.

1. What are the practical differences of these approaches?
2. Will this impact when I try to use this over a general type with a monad? Such as:

   ```
   data Hole = Hole1 Int | Hole2 String

   type C r m a = (a -> m r) -> m r

   exampleFunction :: String -> C Bool Maybe Hole
   exampleFunction s = \t -> do
         x <- t (Hole1 11)
         y <- t (Hole2 "test")
         ...

   continuationFunction :: Hole -> Bool
   continuationFunction (Hole1 x) = False
   continuationFunction (Hole2 y) = True
   ```

Comment: The differences are the usual differences between `type` and `newtype`. `type` synonyms are just a new name for an existing type; they can't be partially applied and you can't make them an `instance` of a class. `newtype`s are separate from the types that they wrap and you can use them to write custom `instance`s. For example you'll have trouble writing an instance of `Monad` for the `type C`.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminHodgson - Do you want to make into an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences are the usual differences between `type` and `newtype`.

A `type` synonym is just a new name for an existing type. `type` synonyms can't be partially applied, because the compiler expands the definition during type checking. For example, this is no good, even with `TypeSynonymInstances`:

```
type TypeCont r a = (a -> r) -> r

instance Monad (TypeCont r) where  -- "The type synonym ‘TypeCont’ should have 2 arguments, but has been given 1"
    return x = ($ x)
    k >>= f = \q -> k (\x -> (f x) q)
```

`newtype`s, while operationally equivalent to the types they wrap, are separate entities in the type system. This means that `newtype`s *can* be partially applied.

```
newtype NewtypeCont r a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r }

instance Monad (NewtypeCont r) where
    return x = Cont ($ x)
    Cont k >>= f = Cont $ \q -> k (\x -> runCont (f x) q)
```